# Convert C char to UTF-16 for transmission over network

Tags: java, c, networking

I'm writing a program that will interface with another machine running Java, and I need to send character arrays over the network. On the receiving end, the Java program uses DataInputStream's readChar() function and expects characters. However, since characters are stored as 1 byte in C, I'm having some trouble writing to the network.

How would I go about converting this?

The actual protocol specification is like so:

```
short: Contains length of char array
char 1, 2, 3...: The characters in the array
```

For background information, my short conversion is like so:

```
char *GetBytesShort(short data)
{
    short net_data = NET_htons(data);
    char *ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(short));
    memcpy(ptr, &net_data, sizeof(short));
    return ptr;
}
```

I've tested it on the receiving end in Java, and the short does get sent over correctly with the correct length, but the character array does not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would converting your text to base64 facilitate the conversion? I know C-to-Java data exchange can be a real pain in the @ :)

Comment: Use `byte` array instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I only really needed to convert the base ASCII characters (no special characters) I just put together a simple solution to send the data over UTF16.

```
char *GetBytesString(char message[])
{
    short str_len = strlen(message);
    char *ptr = (char *) malloc(str_len * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
    {
        int pos = i * 2;
        if (message[i] == '#')
        {
            ptr[pos] = 0;
            ptr[pos + 1] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr[pos] = 0;
            ptr[pos + 1] = message[i];
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Since I needed to be able to send null terminators across the pipe, I convert # to a null character so that strlen can return an accurate length

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.  What you want to do is construct a buffer containing all of your data and then pass that onto the [`send(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) system call to send it along the socket.

The wire format for data is big-endian (aka network byte order), so you should make sure to store your values with the most-significant byte first.  I recommend just manually constructing the byte buffer to avoid endianness issues with your local system (see also [The byte order fallacy](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html)), e.g.:

```
uint16_t dataLen = ...;  // Length of data, in characters
uint16_t *charData = ...;  // Character array

// Constructor packet data buffer to send.  Error checking omitted for
// expository purposes.
size_t packetSize = 2 + dataLen * 2;
uint8_t *packet = malloc(packetSize);

// Copy length into buffer, big-endian
packet[0] = (uint8_t)(dataLen >> 8);
packet[1] = (uint8_t)(dataLen & 0xFF);

// Copy each character into the buffer, big-endian
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
{
    packet[2 + 2*i]     = (uint8_t)(charData[i] >> 8);
    packet[2 + 2*i + 1] = (uint8_t)(charData[i] & 0xFF);
}

// We're done -- send the packet
send(sockfd, packet, packetSize, 0);
```